# invalid 'envir' argument in regression model

Tags: r, debugging

I am having some problems in R. Below is my code. It worked fine until recently and now i get the error:

Error in list(test_drive_enquiries, TV.spend, Display.spend, Social.spend) :
invalid 'envir' argument

Here is my code:

```
library(caret)
# Data partition ----------------------------------------------------------

set.seed(222)
ind<-sample(2,nrow(mtcars), replace=T, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
train<-mtcars[ind==1,]
test<-mtcars[ind==2,]



# Custom control parameters for Machine Learning -----------------------------------------------
# 
custom<-trainControl(method="repeatedcv",
                     number=10,
                     repeats=5, 
                     verboseIter = T)
###Models


set.seed(1234)
model<-train(mpg~wt+qsec,
                        train,
                        method='lm',
                        trControl=custom)
summary(model$finalModel)
```

The error occurs at the model building stage. This same error also occurs if I open a different Rmarkdown document which has a different dataset, with a different regression model.

Also, I can't seem to clear the environment with rm(list=ls())

I get the following error:
Error in rm(list = ls()) : unused argument (list = ls())

Comment: Have you tried this in a fresh R session? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Did anything else happen very recently? Did you update R or install any new packages?

Comment: For part 2 of your question (and do be aware that multipart questions are not considered well-formed on SO) ....  perhaps you have over-written the `rm` function. I'm not sure how you would get rid of the over-written value if it were defined in a manner that didn't accept function names to be remove. When you type "rm"  at the console do you see an argument list that looks like `function (..., list = character(), pos = -1, envir = as.environment(pos), 
    inherits = FALSE)` ?

Comment: I have added a reproducible example. I get the same error with the mtcars dataset

Comment: Well, I don't get any error. So I suggest quitting without saving. Remove any existing ,Rdata files and restart with a fresh session.

Comment: Typing in rm i get the following                                                                                                 function (name, pos = -1L, envir = as.environment(pos), all.names = FALSE, 
    pattern, sorted = TRUE) 
{
    if (!missing(name)) {
        pos <- tryCatch(name, error = function(e) e)
        if (inherits(pos, "error")) {
            name <- substitute(name)
            if (!is.character(name)) 
                name <- deparse(name)
            warning(gettextf("%s converted to character string", 
                sQuote(name)), domain = NA)

Comment: I cannot replicate your error running the code above. Again, was this in a new R session for you? If not, what does `sessionInfo()` show and what does `conflicts(detail=TRUE)` show.

Comment: Some package or code has over-written the stock version of `rm` and removed it's `list` argument. Do remove any .Rdata file and then show all the library calls. At the moment your error is not reproducible.

Comment: You can try `base::rm(list = ls())`, but it general, it's [not recommended to use `rm(list=ls())`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/). It doesn't reset your environment like people think it does.

Comment: conflicts(detail=TRUE) gives me   $.GlobalEnv
[1] "list" "rm"  

$`package:methods`
[1] "body<-"    "kronecker"

$`package:base`
[1] "body<-"    "kronecker" "list"      "rm"

Comment: sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3

Comment: Thank you problem seems to have resolved with the base::rm(list = ls()),. Any ideas why this was happening in the first place?

Comment: Voting to close. The questioner obviously has overwritten the key functions `list`, `rm` and `body<-`, so there's not a lot of value in trying to help him out unless he first fixes those key aspects of R programming. He's been given specific advice on how to do that which he has so far not chosen to follow.

Comment: So you "solved" the problem of the corrupted `rm` but if you have an overwritten version of the `list` function we cannot possibly help you. Fix your installation of R!

Comment: Somehow you created versions of `list()` and `rm()` in your global environment which took over for the "true" functions causing the error. Functions in R aren't protected so you can overwrite existing (even critical) functions if you are not careful. Remove those "bad" versions and you should be fine.